# How to make the extension relocatable?

Tags: postgresql

I don’t know how to make the extension relocatable. Question: how to make the extension move to another scheme. Below, the beginning is described. After that comes the creation of operators, functions, variances, mathematical expectation.

```
create schema IF NOT EXISTS complex;

--Mathematical expectation
--creating a complex data type
create type complex.complex as (re float, im float);
--creation of complex data type with the sum of complex numbers and the amount of numbers--
create type complex.complexSumAndCount as (complexSumVar complex.complex, complexCount integer);

--Creating the function of adding complex numbers
CREATE or REPLACE function complex.complexSumFunction (sum complex.complex, complexTempVar complex.complex)
    RETURNS complex.complex as
$$
BEGIN

    IF sum is not null and complexTempVar is not null then
        sum.re := coalesce(sum.re, 0) + coalesce(complexTempVar.re, 0);
        sum.im := coalesce(sum.im, 0) + coalesce(complexTempVar.im, 0);
    end IF;

    RETURN sum;

end; $$LANGUAGE plpgSQL;
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is clear what you want to do. Clearly if you change the schema name at the top of your script before you run it the type and function will be created in that new schema instead. Did you want to rename the schema after creating the elements or something else?

Comment: I would like it to be done approximately as described in the quote, but I was told that this is not completely true: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html#EXTEND-EXTENSIONS-RELOCATION

Comment: There is no quote in your question. Do you mean the page you just linked to in your comment? Why do you think that is wrong? If you are trying to write an actual extension rather than just some SQL it would be helpful if you posted the control file you are using too.

Comment: https://github.com/norin-co/task/blob/master/script1.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, posting a link to a github repo is probably not the recommended way to improve your question. You also still haven't told me whether you are actually trying to write an extension or not.

I am going to guess that you are not since you don't seem to have a .control file.

If what you are trying to do instead is be able to write

```
select '(6,44)'::complex;
```

rather than

```
select '(6,44)'::complex.complex;
```

then what you need to know about is the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH).

This controls what schemas will be searched for objects (types, tables, functions etc.) when you do not explicitly specify a schema.

So - you have two options. You can add your "complex" schema to your search_path when you want to run queries. Or you can put your "complex" type and functions in your current search_path.

You can set your search_path temporarily (for the current transaction or session) with:

```
SET search_path = public, complex;
```

You can change the default for your user or for your database with something like:

```
ALTER USER myuser SET search_path = public, complex;
ALTER USER mydatabase SET search_path = public complex;
```

The second option is to load your "complex" code into a schema that is already in your search_path. To do this you would remove all reference to a schema from your `script1.sql` file.

```
create type complex as (re float, im float);
create type complexSumAndCount as (complexSumVar complex.complex, complexCount integer);
...
```

Then, when you load it, your types and functions will be created in the first schema that can be found in your search_path. It is good practice to set this to exactly what you want.

```
SET search_path = public;
\i script1.sql
```

or from the command-line

```
PGOPTIONS="--search_path=public" psql -U myuser -d mydb -f script1.sql
```

I hope that helps. If it isn't what you are after then I'm afraid you will need to post a new question and explain precisely what you are trying to do. If you want to have a longer conversation about your problems then the postgresql mailing lists are probably a good place to try.